# Google Maps wont work with an overlaid div

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a google maps javascript v3 application in which the UI has to be overlaid the map (which is, in itself no problem by using full-screen divs and z-index) and i am having an issue:

```
<div id="mapCanvas" style="z-index: -1"></div>
<div id="uiContainer" style="pointer-events: none; z-index: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%...">
    <My UI Here/>
</div>
```

Even though the map works fine by itself, and the uiContainer overlay also works fine for my AJAX UI and pointer-events: none is working (Handlers for click on uiContainer or any of its children wont work unless those children override it with pointer-events: all) i cant interact with the map below the uiContainer.

Any idea is mostly appreciated.

Comment: A live link may help us help you

Comment: I'd rather not open up my dev machine's 80 port as i have not reviewed wamps default httpd configuration, but i can provide source code if that is your wish.

Comment: The relevant code will help. You can also use a free hosting site for link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally got down to it.

The Maps API does NOT like it's container to have it's z-index altered in any way.